# Single solutions with varous database management software

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, cloud

Actually I am new to the software development, I have an idea to create an web application in which I am going to use front end C#.Net and Back end:SQL Server. What happen if my client ask me to use other database management software other than SQL Server? Is there any solutions to run same application without changing the SQL code like dynamic database creation based on the client requirement?

Help me..

Answer (score 0):

Each Database like SQL Server , Oracle is having it's own coding syntax and are totally different . It's not possible to use the code of one DBMS for another.

In most cases SQL statements will work across various Database as it's standard for relational databases . But moreover when work with different databases you need to work in it's own standard.

Also there are different kind of databases available such as RDBMS ,NoSQL etc.. so each different in it's own way.

There might be some tools available to help you to convert one code to another.

Answer (score 0):

You need to isolate database access from the rest of the program so that database specific code is in one place only.

Answer (score 0):

For this convenience you need to learn MVC to perform these tasks. It can happen to certain level but still altogether certains functionalities need specific methods to be called but it increases efficiency...